# How do I determine if a font is going to be commercially used?

Tags: font-licensing

Ok, lets say I downloaded a font off a free font website. Urbanfonts.com for example. When I downloaded the font it has a “README” file attached. I open it, and it has its “conditions”. As for commercial use; I know i have to purchase each licensing separate,but what im not understanding is the use of the product. Say i use it on a banner, i change the color Put a shadow....would i need a licensing for it? Im not coping the font onto a file to share.im using it to type a few words or name.

Answer (score 4):

"Commercial use" means **using** the font as part of a design for **anything** which you are selling or otherwise profiting from, as in advertising or client work.

"**Use**" means use, it is not the same as "share".

So, yes. If you set type in the font, add a shadow, color it or whatever.. then save as a PDF/PNG.. and give that to a client in exchange for payment or post it as an advertisement on your social media page... yes, you are using the font commercially.